# Three.js transparency artefact on not transparent object

Tags: three.js, overlay, transparent, depth

[Transparency artefact problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T5Mug.jpg)

Hello,
I have an issue with three.js. I import a "big" glb model on my scene which is not transparent, but if the model is covered by itself on the camera view, the foreground become transparent. (as you can see on the picture, the background montain is on foreground)

I tried some solutions like :

- depthTest to false on glb material
- sortOrder to false
- Use logarithmicDepthBuffer
- Change material transparent to false
- Change alphaTest from 0 to 1 by 0.1 steps

But nothing works. If someone have the solution :)

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

Rendering of transparent objects cannot be done quite properly. You first need to render any non-transparent objects, and then render transparent surfaces from back to front, so that any new ones blend on top of what was behind it. There are a number of cases where this cannot be done, especially when rendering transparent objects that may overlap themselves.

Fixing this would involve cutting the problematic objects (even single triangles) into smaller pieces so that the ordering can be preserved, and that is often nearly impossible. Since you are working with Three.js, see if you could alter your design so that this isn't a problem, or that the artifacts of incorrect rendering order aren't too much noticeable.

Comment: The said limitations apply to all normal 3d rendering, not just WebGL or Three.js. You could avoid them entirely by using a raytracer, but that is much slower and requires an entirely different implementation.

Comment: In your particular problem, can you render the terrain without transparency and then the water with transparency, both with depth tests enabled? I can't quite recall how Three.js handles that but in principle it should be able to render non-transparent objects first.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. But in my situation the terrain is not transparent at all... and I think that the problem d'ont come from water because if I remove the Water the problem still continue :( I Will try to enable depth test on the water.

Comment: can you share the glb model?

Comment: You can download my glb file here : https://1fichier.com/?z6hwqimlej12yw3uzaxv

Comment: I think that what I'm looking for have a solution because when I open my file with : https://gltf.insimo.com/ there is no problems but if I open the gbl with https://gltf-viewer.donmccurdy.com/ There is the same problem... but each solution is based on three.js

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to *donmccurdy* which have find my solution on the three.js forum.

Finally my glb file was Transparent :( So there is two solutions.

**Solution 1:**

Find how the model is transparent and fix it.

**Solution 2:**

Changing it back to opaque, and restoring the default depthWrite value.

```
mesh = content.getObjectByName('mesh_0');
mesh.material.transparent = false;
mesh.material.depthWrite = true;
```